# Bootstrap + Mobile Menu Overlay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I have a navbar that's defined like the following:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color:orange;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="color:#000 !important;">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color:#000;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color:#000;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="color:#000;"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="/home" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/help">help</a></li>
            <li><a href="/help">contact</a></li>            
         </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="navbar-right">
        <div class="visible-xs">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">2016</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="_blank">Q1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q4</a></li>                
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">2017</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="_blank">Q1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q4</a></li>                
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="hidden-xs">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">2016</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="_blank">Q1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q4</a></li>                
              </ul>
           </li>

           <li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">2017</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="_blank">Q1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Q4</a></li>                
              </ul>             
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar looks and works like I want on bigger screens. But on mobile, it doesn't work correctly. As you can see in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sxsiSwAtdb#), the nav menu pushes the main content (the Lorem Ipsum) down. However, I want the nav menu to appear on top of the content, so that the mobile nav appears on top of the Lorem Ipsum stuff. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want fixed header?

Comment: Use `<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"...`

Comment: yeah maybe you just want a fixed navigation bar/header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want like this:

http://www.bootply.com/9OB6nhtg4i#

```
    @media (max-width:768px) {
       .navbar {
         position: absolute;
       }
    }
```

Add this css and try.

Answer (score 1):

U need to use `navbar-fixed-top` class and set top padding for `main` block:

```
main {
padding-top: 60px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/aROSWOLDZY